# Publicly expose local [ASP Web-] API

Tags: windows, azure, iis, networking, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to expose an ASP WebApi to the internet for testing purposes. I thought that this can't be too difficult, but here I am, asking for help. I'm a novice when it comes to networking so please, be as explicit with instructions.

When I run my API application locally, hitting `https://localhost:44316/{api-method}` (or `http://localhost:49511/{api-method}`) executes the API method. How can I configure IIS/my machine/firewall/whatever-I-need-to in order to be able to hit the API at `https://<my public IP>:44316/{api-method}` (or `http://<my public IP>:49511/{api-method}`)? The ports 44316 and 49511 are defaults, I didn't select them (I'm guess that's obvious and probably irrelevant).

I'm also working on an Azure VM (this may or may not be relevant) and have added endpoints on ports 44316 and 49511 (both public and private, and not behind load balancing) already.

Additionally, I'm not overly concerned by security (though more knowledge won't go amiss) as I'll teardown anything that I've set up to get this working once I've done with testing.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Adding the endpoints in the Azure portal is one step. You'll also need to open them on your Firewall if you have one up. The way to do this depends on what kind of server you're running. Assuming it's a Windows 2012 server, go to the Server menu, check Tools -> Firewall, and add Rules for inbound and outbound on the ports that you want.

One thing to note is that Azure doesn't respond to 'ping' commands in the expected way, so it may not look like your rules are working if you're just using Ping to test. However it will work with your API.

I have a blog post that breaks down steps to run a multiplayer game using Azure which shows the Firewall setup. Steps 6, and 10 are the important ones but you've already done 10. http://secondtruth.com/2014/12/how-to-simulate-a-tiny-universe-in-azure/

Here's the Windows 2012 Firewall setup in particular http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall